# Open set in $R^d$ is the union of almost disjoint closed cubes.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I understand everything in this lemma and in its proof except one moment.

"...we note
that given x ∈ $\mathbb{O}$ (open set) there exists a cube of side length $2^{-n}$ (obtained from successive bisections of the original grid) that contains x and that is
entirely contained in $\mathbb{O}$."

What is about a point in open set which lies on the side of cube? I agree that this point belongs to one or another cubes  whose boundaries pass through this point (maybe there are many cubes whose boundaries or cornes pass through this point but it is not important in my question). But this lemma says that there is one cube which contains this point and I think it mean that we talk about an interior of this cube.

How this lemma works for points which lie on sides or corners?

What do I misunderstand?

Edit: To which cube does belong a point which lies on boundaries of cubes?

Edit: In generally, I understand that it is not so important to which cube  it does belongs. But I confused by "every point in open set belongs to one cube".

Fragment from my book:
[image]

Comment: A closed cube includes all its boundary. (all points on the surface; either one on a face or one of the corners.)

Comment: Maybe your trouble is with the word "contains"? Here "$S$ contains $x$" I think means just set-theoretically: $x \in S$, for any set $S$. Maybe you thought it means "$x \in S^\circ$", the interior of the set.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it. Lets this point (from our open set) lies on the surface of cube A. For which cube does it belongs? It belongs to A? But there is also another cube B which intersects with cube A through this point. So to which cube does it belongs ?

Comment: Let's take two cubes which intersect only at theire boundaries. And lets take a point which lies at this boundary. To which cube does it belong?

Comment: In the proof it is written "...there is a cube that contains...". But in my example there is not a cube. There are two cubes.

Comment: There are point which lie in exactly one cube. And they are points that belong to interiors of cubes . But how we deal with points that lie on the boundaries?

Comment: Right, exactly: there are two cubes possibly. But this situation does not bother us! We are not trying to give a disjoint union. We are trying to give an *almost disjoint union*, for exactly the reason you are giving.

Comment: I understand. I dont know how to accept comment as answer but I got the answer. Thatnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's produce a concrete example. Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the open upper half plane, i.e $\{(x,y):y>0\}.$ We implement Stein and Shakarchi's algorithm.

The closed cube $Q$ determined by $\{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2)\}$ is fully accepted during the $N=0$ stage. However, the closed cube $\{(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(1,1)\}$ is only tentatively accepted during the $N=0$ stage.

During the $N=1$ stage, the closed cube $Q'=\{(1,\frac{1}{2}),(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}),(\frac{3}{2},1),(1,1)\}$ is fully accepted.

So for instance $(x,y)=(\frac{5}{4},1)$ belongs to $Q\cap Q'$, but does not belong to $Q^\circ\cap Q'^\circ = \emptyset.$

"A countable collection of closed cubes $Q$ whose interiors $Q^\circ$ are disjoint, with $\mathbb{H}=\,$ the union of this collection."